# AFNetworking totalBytesExpectedToRead

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am attempting to display download progress. But the values I get for progress are not between 0 and 1. 
They are:
-2394.000000
-5290.000000
-8186.000000
-11074.000000
-13970.000000
-17482.000000
-20378.000000
-21826.000000
.
.
.
-153802.000000
1.000000

I am sure the issue is with totalBytesExpectedToRead. What property does AFNetworking look for when making the download call to get the total size?

Comment: Show your code that is getting these numbers. Make sure you have the correct types.

Comment: The code is working fine, actually. I tested it on a download from mediafire. When I try to download from a local server, then I get these numbers. The issue, I am sure is with the local server's protocol. I just need to know how AFNetworking tries to obtain the total download size

Comment: Perhaps the local server is not providing the size. Crank-up Charles Proxy and look at the messages.

Comment: Zaph has a point here. Can you check if your server sets Content-Length header?

Comment: It doesn't set Content-Length header. So that should be the problem then. However, on the last call to setDownloadProgressBlock, the correct value of totalBytesExpectedToRead is passed to the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server needs to set `Content-Length` in the header so expected size is known. Of course when the entire file has completed download the expected file size is known.